# Inner join using eloquent in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a doubt that I couldn't find an answer anywhere.
I'm new to eloquent and to make the basic stuff it is excelent!
Now I need to query data from different tables and I was wondering if I can do it with eloquent.
I have two models:

```
class Worker extends Model {

protected $table = 'workers';
public $timestamps = true;

public function area()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Area');
}

}
```

And this one

```
class Area extends Model {

protected $table = 'areas';
public $timestamps = true;

public function worker()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Worker');
}

}
```

So basically a worker belongs to an area and an area has many workers.
Now I want to show in a table the name of the worker and the name of the area that he belongs to.

I can do it using the query builder but I wanted to know if I can do it with eloquent.

I saw a post in laracast with this code:

```
$workers = Worker::with('area')->get();
```

Now when I use that I get the following error:

```
Class 'Area' not found
```

I don't know why I get that error when the function 'area' exists in the Worker class and in the WorkerController I'm using

```
use App\Area;
```

What I want to be able to do is the following:

```
@foreach ($workers as $worker)
<td>{{ $worker->name }}</td>
<td>{{ $worker->lastname }}</td>
<td>{{ $worker->areas->name }}</td>
@endforeach
```

Like I said, I already I'm able to accompish this using laravel's query builder but I just want to know if I can make more use of the Eloquent :)
Thank you for your time.

Just in case anyone asks here is my raw query:

```
$workers = DB::table('workers')
                     ->join('areas', 'areas.id', '=', 'workers.area_id')
                     ->select('workers.*', 'areas.name as area')
                     ->get();
```

That's the one I'm using and it works perfectly fine, thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing namespaces in your relations.

```
public function area()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Area');
}
```

and

```
public function worker()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Worker');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use function like you named in model "area" not "areas":

```
@foreach ($workers as $worker)
    <td>{{ $worker->name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $worker->lastname }}</td>
    <td>{{ $worker->area->name }}</td>
@endforeach
```